# How to open VSCode Remote-WSL by right click

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to open the current folder on VSCode Remote-WSL by right click from Windows File Explorer.
How can I make it? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To add Windows context menu for a directory to open it in Visual Studio Code within Remote WSL, add these windows registry keys as admin:

```
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\WSLVSCode\command" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "wsl.exe code `wslpath '%1'`"
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\WSLVSCode" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "Open in WSL VSCode"
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\WSLVSCode" /v Icon /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```

Update the correct path for icon file.

Comment: I would use the --remote flag as visual studio recommends (code --remote wsl+<distro name> <path in WSL>)

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with `code --remote` because the path in WSL is not the same as the windows path. The answer above does work, but I had to use %V instead of %1 in the command (so it can also work in Directory/Background/shell), and also had to add a backslash before the %, or change it to `wsl.exe code $(wslpath '%V')`.

Comment: I was also annoyed by the command prompt that momentarily pops up with this method, so I fixed it by wrapping the command in some vbscript code, so my final command key looks like: `mshta vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""Wscript.Shell"").Run(""wsl.exe code $(wslpath '%V')"", 0, False)(window.close)")`

Comment: Note that this solution only works when right-clicking on a subdirectory, not when right-clicking the empty space in the current directory as I tend to do, nor does it include files.  For the former, add to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`, and the latter, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell`, which is more consistent with the default non-wsl VSCode shortcut.

Comment: Also, this method breaks when the Windows path has spaces.  This is fixed by using the value `"wsl.exe code \"\`wslpath '%1'\`\""` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this for 'Open folder in WSL':
Make a registry file (.reg), paste code and run:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> ; Delete old entries [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\VSCode]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\VSCode]
>
> ; Add a sub-menu for right click on a folder
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\VSCode] "MUIVerb"="Visual Studio
> Code" "ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\ContextMenus\VSCode"
> "Icon"="C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
>
> ; Add a sub-menu for right click on the background
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\VSCode]
> "MUIVerb"="Visual Studio Code"
> "ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\ContextMenus\VSCode"
> "Icon"="C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\VSCode]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\VSCode\shell]
>
> ; Set up text and icons
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\VSCode\shell\open]
> "MUIVerb"="Open folder" "Icon"="C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS
> Code\Code.exe"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\VSCode\shell\openwsl]
> "MUIVerb"="Open folder in WSL" "Icon"="C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS
> Code\Code.exe"
>
> ; Set up commands
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\VSCode\shell\open\command]
> @=""C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "%V""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\VSCode\shell\openwsl\command]
> @="wsl.exe --cd "%V" code ." ; This will open the current folder
> WSL-side, and then run code from there

Result: [Sample image](https://gist.github.com/mbartelsm/be2a8ea761e5358cd04e3777d107b186#file-sample-png)

from: https://gist.github.com/mbartelsm/be2a8ea761e5358cd04e3777d107b186#file-vscode_context-reg

And this for 'Open with code in WSL' (open file in WSL):
Make a registry file (.reg), paste code and run:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\VSCodeWsl] @="Open w&ith Code in WSL"
> "Icon"="C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\VSCodeWsl\command] @="wsl.exe code
> "$(wslpath '%1')""

result: [open-with-code-in-wsl sample](https://matuszykrafa.github.io/open-with-code-in-wsl/sample2.png)

from: https://github.com/matuszykrafa/open-with-code-in-wsl

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28228057)

Answer (score 0):

Combining [Open with Code (WSL) for folder](https://gist.github.com/mbartelsm/be2a8ea761e5358cd04e3777d107b186#file-vscode_context-reg) and [Open with Code (WSL) for file](https://github.com/matuszykrafa/open-with-code-in-wsl).

Thanks to [@Mogzol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336461/how-to-open-vscode-remote-wsl-by-right-click/74911534#comment108533369_60274090) for solving the pop-up window.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; You may replace
; C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe
; with 
; C:\\Users\\Your User Name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe
; for correct VS Code icon


; Add the option for right-click on a folder
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\VSCodeWSL]
@="Open with Code (WSL)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\VSCodeWSL\command]
@="mshta vbscript:Execute(\"CreateObject(\"\"Wscript.Shell\"\").Run(\"\"wsl.exe code \"\"\"\"$(wslpath '%V')\"\"\"\"\"\", 0, False)(window.close)\")"


; Add the option for right-click in the background of current folder
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\VSCodeWSL]
@="Open with Code (WSL)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\VSCodeWSL\command]
@="mshta vbscript:Execute(\"CreateObject(\"\"Wscript.Shell\"\").Run(\"\"wsl.exe code \"\"\"\"$(wslpath '%V')\"\"\"\"\"\", 0, False)(window.close)\")"


; Add the option for right-click on a file
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\VSCodeWSL]
@="Open with Code (WSL)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\VSCodeWSL\command]
@="mshta vbscript:Execute(\"CreateObject(\"\"Wscript.Shell\"\").Run(\"\"wsl.exe code \"\"\"\"$(wslpath '%1')\"\"\"\"\"\", 0, False)(window. Close)\")"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file and paste this.
2. Save with .bat file extension.
3. Run file with admin privileges.

```bash
   @echo off
   color 04
   title Open VSCode with Wsl option in right click context menu 

:: ############################################################################################################
   set "KeyOfOpeningSpesificFolder=HKCR\Directory\shell\Wsl and VSCode"
   REG ADD "%KeyOfOpeningSpesificFolder%" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "Open VSCode with Wsl"
   REG ADD "%KeyOfOpeningSpesificFolder%\command" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "wsl --cd \"%%V\" code . "
:: ############################################################################################################
   set "KeyOfOpeningCurrentFolder=HKCR\Directory\Background\shell\Wsl and VSCode"
   REG ADD "%KeyOfOpeningCurrentFolder%" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "Open VSCode with Wsl"
   REG ADD "%KeyOfOpeningCurrentFolder%\command" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "wsl --cd \"%%V\" code ."
:: ############################################################################################################
   pause>nul
   exit /b
```

**Explanation:** First part is to add a directory context menu and the second part is to add directory background context menu.

[image: At the end, it will be shown like this.]